# Laravel 12815 segmentation fault (core dumped) php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

Tags: sql-server, laravel, docker

I am using an external MS SQL Server for a Laravel App.

However, when I execute the following command:

```sh
$ php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

I get the following error

> Migrating ... [1]    12815 segmentation fault (core dumped)  php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

This is a weird error.

I am using a Docker container `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest` which I have seen in other servers, it works all right for me executing the migration for the first time. But if I execute again, I get that error. However, deleting the database and recreating it manually, then the artisan migration command works.

But the problem now, is that in the new server, this error persists, even if I destroy and create again the database.

Does anybody know how to fix this or why this error is showing? Any work around?

Comment: Can try one by one ? ```php artisan migrate:fresh``` and Seed later 
```php artisan db:seed ```

Comment: Hello, the error actually occurs right away in the migration process.